# How do I make React App Page show showing on Github?

Tags: reactjs, github

I need help on my react app portfolio that I've uploaded to Github. Link: https://amex23.github.io/my-portfolio/

The pages doesn't show up, thoug it runs fine in my local computer.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

The links to your content are broken.

In your source they are like:

https://amex23.github.io/amex23/my-portfolio.git/static/js/main.3ac9e73c.chunk.js

They should be like:

https://amex23.github.io/my-portfolio/static/js/2.df4fd8bb.chunk.js

You can open up your index.html and change them all manually but there is something wrong with your build step or site config that made them that way